# Hubot change IRC channel topic

Tags: irc, hubot

I'd like our Hubot to manage the topic of certain IRC channels.  When I have hubot send "/TOPIC #channel New Topic" that text just ends up in the channel.

I know I can add a listener for IRC topic changes (like [irc-topic.coffee](https://github.com/hackatron/hackatron-hubot/blob/master/scripts/irc-topic.coffee)) with:

```
robot.adapter.bot.addListener 'topic', (channel, topic) ->
```

But is there an interface to setting the topic or a way to coerce [hubot-irc adapter](https://github.com/nandub/hubot-irc) into send a raw IRC command?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://gist.github.com/ConnorWGarvey/6089889

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nandub/hubot-irc/blob/master/src/irc.coffee#L40

it looks like you just setup the listener and then `topic = "thing the topic should be"`